# "Please Insert a Disk into Drive \Device\Harddisk1\..." when trying to use putty

Tags: windows-7, putty

I am trying to use putty, the ssh-client, on my W7 laptop. When I try to load or remove sessions, I get an error

> Please Insert a Disk into Drive \Device\harddisk1\Dr6

with buttons Cancel, Try again and Continue. None of them does anything, and the windows just keeps coming endlessly. The only way to close it is to kill the putty process (from spawning new popups), and then pressing any of these three buttons.

It said originally \DR1, until I removed something called "Google File CD-Gadget USB Device". I think putty is trying to access an non-existing disk, but why?

The only post about this problem I found was fixed with a reboot, but I have been having this problem for a long time.

Comment: Are you trying to use PuTTY Portable? If so, did you copy the whole thing (folder and all) off the USB key before removing it?

Comment: @JustinPearce I am using the latest(0.62) standalone binary (putty.exe)

Answer (score 1):

FYI -

I have the same recurring issue. Reboot fixed it, but this popped up again randomly. Based on Putty docs, I added registry entry for RandSeedFile, as shown below and created a blank file at that location. It has fixed the issue for now, without a reboot.

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY]
"RandSeedFile"="c:\apps\putty.rnd"

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Same no disk error I always get on **in-active putty window**, on my D drive (DVD ROM drive)

This error went when I:

1. Restart session (from putty menu, select ***Restart Session***, and logged in any server (activate your old putty session)
2. Open/close my DVD drive without dvd disk (you can insert dvd disk also)
3. Click, Cancel, Try again few times, on putty error message window

no err now :)

Hope, it work for you